# Cómo consolidar la información de una tabla en una línea en Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quisiera saber cual es la manera optima de realizar la siguiente consolidación de información en Postgres. De la tabla superior en la imagen deseo llegar a la inferior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es tener el valor del último movimiento realizado en cada una de las características (Car#), así como la última actividad generada. En este caso por ejemplo, para la etapa 3 no existe actividad, o simplemente no se ha generado aún.  En cuanto a las características, algunas deben mantener una concatenación de valores (car1) y otras simplemente el dato reciente (Car2-4)

He intentado solucionar el asunto haciendo uso de las funciones de ventana.

Un código similar a este:

```
select      distinct
            empleado, 
            first_value(etapa) over (partition by empleado order by etapa desc) AS etapa,
            nth_value(activitdad, 2) over (partition by empleado order by fecha_end_actividad desc) AS Activity_Type

from        tabla
```

Sin embargo, sólo para estos dos datos estoy obteniendo un resultado como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro entender muy bien porque aparece una segunda línea con un valor null en la etapa.

Existe alguna manera de hacer esto de forma más óptima y elegante?

De antemano gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Es posible hacerlo usando la función ventana `FIRST_VALUE` en una subconsulta combinado con funciones de agregación en la consulta principal:

```
with cte as (
  select empleado,
         etapa,
         fecha_end_actividad,
         car1,
         first_value(actividad) over (
           partition by empleado
           order by actividad is null,
                    etapa desc,
                    fecha_end_actividad desc) as actividad,
         first_value(car2) over (
           partition by empleado
           order by car2 is null or car2 = '',
                    etapa desc,
                    fecha_end_actividad desc) as car2,
         first_value(car3) over (
           partition by empleado
           order by car3 is null or car3 = '',
                    etapa desc,
                    fecha_end_actividad desc) as car3,
         first_value(car4) over (
           partition by empleado
           order by car4 is null or car4 = '',
                    etapa desc,
                    fecha_end_actividad desc) as car4
    from tabla
)
select empleado,
       max(etapa) as etapa,
       max(actividad) as actividad,
       string_agg(case when car1 = '' then null else car1 end,
                  '-' order by etapa, fecha_end_actividad) as car1,
       max(car2) as car2,
       max(car3) as car3,
       max(car4) as car4
 from cte
group by empleado
```

Notarás que la lógica que determina cual valor usar para las columnas `actividad`, `car2`, `car3` y `car4` depende enteramente de cómo se define la claúsula `ORDER BY` en la función ventana `FIRST_VALUE`. Yo lo definí según entendí tu lógica, pero tal vez necesites hacer ajustes menores por ese lado. Pero la estructura general de la consulta debería ser correcta.

Comment: simplemente el mejor. Gracias por esta valiosa ayuda. Veo como se comporta la consulta

Comment: @db_: Simplifiqué la consulta. Me di cuenta que era mucho mas sencillo usar `first_value` en vez de `row_number`. Permite llegar mas directamente al resultado. De todas formas, el principio de base es la misma: usar las funciones ventana en la subconsulta + hacer el `GROUP BY` en la consulta principal.

Comment: Hola sstan. También estuve probando con la solución dada. Realicé una pequeña modificación y obtuve una solución también válida.

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo uso de la solución dada por @sstan realicé la siguiente modificación obteniendo la solución buscada:

```
select      distinct
            empleado, 
            first_value(etapa) over (partition by empleado order by etapa desc) AS etapa,
            first_value(activitdad) over (partition by empleado order by when activitidad is not null and car1 is not null then actividad else 0 end desc) AS car1,
            first_value(activitdad) over (partition by empleado order by when activitidad is not null and car3 is not null then actividad else 0 end desc) AS car3

from        tabla
```

Comment: Me intriga tu solución. ¿Como lograstes combinar esta solución incluyendo la columna donde tenías que concatenar los valores en vez de solamente tomar el valor mas reciente? (En tu pregunta es `car1`). O es que ya no necesitas hacer esto. Porque si no tienes ese caso especial, la consulta que tienes aquí queda bien simplificada.

Comment: Logré negociar esa parte para no tener que generar esa concatenación. Al final vimos que no era tan relevante tener todos esos valores.